# ¿Es correcto decir "hasta que se llegue a un equilibrio entre lo internal y lo external"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

Estoy intentando traducir la frase:

> ... until an equilibrium is reached between the internal and the external.

Donde "the internal" y "the external" son cosas abstractas (es decir, no se refieren a nada concreto).
Lo que se me ocurre es:

> ... hasta que se llegue a un equilibrio entre lo internal y lo external

Pero todavía, tras pensarlo un poco, no estoy seguro.

Comment: A mi me suena mejor utilizar las palabras "un equilibro entre el interior y el exterior"

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con la observación de @fernando.reyes La frase correcta es "...hasta que se llegue a un equilibrio entre lo interior y lo exterior" o "entre lo interno y lo externo". Fernando, deberias escribirlo en una  respuesta.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta de Mike: *equilibrio entre lo interno y lo externo* quizás, pero dependiendo del contexto, quizás algo no tan breve quedaría mejor, por ejemplo *temperatura al interior del sistema*, *presión al interior*, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No creo que existan las palabras *internal* y *external* en el español. Las traducciones correctas de estos términos son:

> **Externo/Interno**

y puesto que son adjetivos con género pueden presentarse también como:

> **Externa/Interna**

No creo que la traducción correcta sea *interior* y *exterior*, puesto que son cognados y deberían poderse traducir igualitariamente.